# Get the tag link in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I am writing an article about Football and it contains word such as FIFA, Football etc. Similarly,  I would add FIFA, Football tag as well.

Once done, i will publish the article. At the front end of the post, I want to see the word like FIFA and Football linked with the link like domain.com/tag/fifa/ and  domain.com/tag/football/.

How is it possible ? Is there any plugin ?

Comment: This is possible. You can do it using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page using tags to find related posts.

```
<?php
$tag = single_tag_title('', false);
echo '<h2>Tag: '.$tag.'</h2>';

$args = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tag,
            'terms' => $tag,
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );?>

<?php foreach( $postslist as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
      <span class="timestamp"><?php echo mysql2date('j M Y', $post->post_date) ;?></span></h2>
      <p class="about"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This was written by Mihai Iorga at [Get posts all posts by Tag / URL Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484945/get-posts-all-posts-by-tag-url-wordpress)